# Does ◻(∀x)[Px ≡ ◻(E!x → Qx)] and ◻(∀x)(Qx → ◻E!x) entail ◻(∀x){Px ≡ ◻[E!x & (E!x → Qx)]}?

Tags: modal-logic, free-logic

Say we are working in a free quantified modal logic system S5. Would the following argument be valid:

◻(∀x)[Px ≡ ◻(E!x → Qx)] (Premise)

◻(∀x)(Qx → ◻E!x) (Premise)

◻(∀x){Px ≡ ◻[E!x & (E!x → Qx)]} (1, 2)

Comment: I’m guessing those “E!”s aren’t existential quantifiers, since they wouldn’t have legitimate scopes. And they’re not negations, since then the variables wouldn’t have predicates. So are they just negated predicate E?

Comment: @ChristopherE "E!" is the existence predicate in [free logic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-free/).

Comment: @Eliran thanks - can free logic have variables with multiple quantifiers?

Comment: @ChristopherE It has the same rules for binding variables as classical predicate logic. Note that x is not bound twice here, because 'E!' is a predicate, not a quantifier.